# Complemento a 1 y complemento a 2

Tags: java

Por qué en este código:

```
int a = 2, b = 0, c = 0;
c = -a; // resultado c = -2
c = ~b; // resultado c = -1
```

¿Por qué en el primer caso `c=-2` y en el segundo `c=-1`?

Answer (score 16):

**1. Operador `-`**

Este operador es sencillo, simplemente obtienes el mismo valor cambiado de signo. Si es positivo, pasa a negativo; y si es negativo, pasa a positivo.

Por lo que en tu caso `-a` dónde `a=2` el resultado es `-a=-2`

**2. Operador `~` que se llama bitwise complement**

Esto es más interesante. Lo que hace este operador es **intercambiar** la representación en **binario** del número. Es decir, pongamos como ejemplo el `~2`:

- 2 en binario es: `0000 0010`
- hacemos un intercambio de sus bits (todos los `0` a `1` y todos los `1` a `0`) el resultado es: `1111 1101` que es la representación en **binario** de `-3`.
- Por lo que `~2 = -3`

Vayamos a tu caso concreto, que es `~0`

- partimos del `0` que en binario es: `0000 0000`
- Intercambiamos todos los bits: `1111 1111` que es la representación en **binario** de `-1`.
- Por lo que `~0 = -1`

Tienes más documentación de los operadores [aquí](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm) (para java).

Para acabar simplemente comentar que cómo dicen en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791328/how-does-the-bitwise-complement-operator-work) del SO original:

### El operador bitwise (~) SÓLO INTERCAMBIA LOS BITS. Depende de la máquina interpretarlos.

¿Por qué comento esto? A simple vista el operador `~` es simplemente cambiar de signo y restarle `1`. Es decir:

```
~x = -x - 1
```

Me imagino que por ahí iba tu pregunta. Pero depende del ordenador la interpretación de los bits del operador `~` no siempre es el mismo.

Pero como dice [Paul Vargas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/634/paul-vargas) en el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31160055#31160055):

> Puesto que la pregunta está etiqueta con [java](/questions/tagged/java), en [java](/questions/tagged/java) no existe `unsigned`

Lo que significa que en [java](/questions/tagged/java) no tendría que haber resultados raros (que sí los hay, por ejemplo, en [c](/questions/tagged/c) cuándo se trabaja con `unsigned` - mirad [este link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interesting-facts-bitwise-operators-c/))

Comment: `2 en binario es: 0000 0010` Bueno, en realidad un `int`en Java ocupa 32 bits - pero esto no altera la respuesta.

Comment: @leonbloy Sí, pero he reducido a 8 bit al no ser necesario en este ejemplo :)

Answer (score 4):

En la primera asignación `c = -a;` estás usando el símbolo "menos" para negar el número contenido en `a` por lo que el valor de `c` será el negativo de `a`: -2. Es el equivalente a multiplicar a por -1.

En el segundo caso estás usando el operador de negación a nivel de bit `~` también llamado "tilde". Este operador invierte los 0s y 1s del número. En este caso el número es 0 y su representación en binario es 000000000. Al aplicar la negación binaria el número binario resultante es 11111111.

El número binario 11111111 representa al número -1 en decimal dado que se usa la representación "complemento a 2". Para aprender más sobre el complemento a 2 puedes leer la [entrada de wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_a_dos)

Answer (score 4):

Primeramente podemos comenzar revisando de qué se trata cada una de las operaciones:

- #### Complemento a 1

  El complemento a 1 de un número binario se obtiene cambiando `0` → `1` y `1` → `0`. Es decir, se cambia cada bit por su complemento. Por ejemplo (usando un `byte`):

  ```sql
    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0    Original        ( =  2 )
    ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
    1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1    Complemento a 1 ( = -3 )
  ```

  Veáse en Wikipedia el [*Complemento a uno*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_a_uno).
- #### Complemento a 2

  El complemento a 2 de un número binario se obtiene tomando el complemento a 1 del número y luego sumando 1 al bit menos significativo (*LSB* o *Least Significant Bit*). Tomando el ejemplo anterior:

  ```sql
    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0    Original        ( =  2 )
    ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
    1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1    Complemento a 1 ( = -3 )
  +               1
    ───────────────
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0    Complemento a 2 ( = -2 )
  ```

  El complemento a 2 de 0 es 0 (`00000000` → `11111111` → `00000000`) y el complemento a 2 del número más negativo, *`Byte.MIN_VALUE`*, es el mismo (`10000000` → `01111111` → `10000000`).

  Veáse en Wikipedia el [*Complemento a dos*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_a_dos).

Ahora, analizando el código:

- #### `c = -a; // resultado c = -2`

  Si `a = 2` (positivo), entonces `c = -a` se calcula:

  ```sql
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010    Original         ( =  2 )
  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1101    Complemento a 1  ( = -3 )
  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110    Sumando 1 al LSB ( = -2 )
  ```

  O el complemento a 2.

  Veáse [§15.15.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.4) dentro de la [*The Java Language Specification*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html).
- #### `c = ~b; // resultado c = -1`

  Si `b = 0` (positivo), entonces `c = ~b` se calcula:

  ```sql
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    Original         ( =  0 )
  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111    Complemento a 1  ( = -1 )
  ```

  Veáse [§15.15.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.5) dentro de la [*The Java Language Specification*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html).