# Transformar un string de un número binario signado en su complemento a dos en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un `String` de un número binario signado y **quiero transformarlo en su complemento a dos**. Pueden ayudarme a hacerlo?

Por ejemplo transformar `cjunk` en su complemento a dos:

```
Dim cjunk As String = 11111110101101110000
```

Sería:

```
complemento_a_dos_sin_adición = 00000001010010001111
complemento_a_dos             = 00000001010010010000
```

Pensaba hacerlo con un bucle `for` y un `while` para la adición

Comment: ¿Puedes ser esto lo que necesitas? http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/16829/7242 - Hacer la operación con `~` o bien esto: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20251153/1468942

Comment: @MiquelColl Muchas gracias! Su vincula esta muy interressante, esplecialmente para `~`. Sin embargo, esta es para los **int**, no sé como hacerlo con un **string**

Comment: Transforma el string a un int :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y cómo indico en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/16829/7242) (curiosamente es mía) puedes hacer el complemento a 2 con el bitwise `~`, pero si quieres hacerlo con un bucle y a mano:

```
Dim complemento_a_dos_sin_adición As String
For Each c As Char in cjunk 
    If c = "0" Then complemento_a_dos_sin_adición  += "1"
    Else complemento_a_dos_sin_adición  += "0"
    End If
Next
```

Aún así otra forma de hacerlo es transformar `cjunk` a un `int` y trabajar con el bitwise:

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt(cjunk, 2);
```

Ya tienes en `foo` el número y puedes aplicar el bitwise.

Si quieres aplicar el bitwise también a mano, es sencillo:

```
Dim resultInt As Int
If foo >= 0 Then resultInt = foo*-1 - 1
Else If foo < 0 Then resultInt = foo*-1 + 1
End If
```

Y entonces volver a transformar el `resultInt` a binario.

```
Dim result As String = Convert.ToString(resultInt, 2).PadLeft(16, "0"c) '16 bits
```

Comment: Creo que VB.NET no permite `char` dentro de comillas simples... _¿O si?_

Comment: ¡oooops! ¡gracias!