# ¿Cómo sabe C si el valor int guardado es signed o unsigned?

Tags: c, memoria, ram

Ayer tuve una pregunta rondándome la cabeza.

Estuve modificando valores en la RAM de un programa que hice con Cheat Engine. Si el valor era `int`, y lo modificaba para que subiese hasta `2.147.483.647` pero después pasaba a números negativos (`-2.147.483.648`). Ya se que esto es debido a lo de que la mitad es para positivos y la otra mitad para negativos.

Int:

De `-2.147.483.648` a `2.147.483.647`

Unsigned Int:

De `0` a `4.294.967.296`

Mi pregunta es, al imprimir los números o hacer operaciones, ¿cómo sabe C si el número es`int` o `unsigned int`?

Mucha gracias y saludos :)

Comment: Los bits son meros "0" y "1" que pueden ser interpretados como un caracter, un entero, un punto flotante, un decimal codificado en binario, una instrucción en código de máquina (real o virtual) o cualquier cosa que se te ocurra. No nay nada en el contenido que te diga lo que es.

Comment: *Los bits son meros "0" y "1" que pueden ser interpretados como un caracter, un entero, un punto flotante...* Los carácteres ocupan un byte en ARM, lo que vendrían siendo 8 bits, los enteros y flotantes por lo general entre 4 y 8 bytes, lo que vendrían siendo entre 32 o 64 bits. Tu mismo lo has dicho **un solo bit** no puede tener más de dos estados.

Comment: *¿Cómo sabe C si el valor int guardado es signed o unsigned?...* C no necesita saber nada, porque es un idioma, esto es mas bien una pregunta de implementacion, la pregunta podria ser asi: *¿Cómo sabe la CPU si el valor int guardado es signed o unsigned?* Ahi es diferente y la respuesta es **no**, no sabe, no distingue. La CPU no es adivina. Es el compilador (o el mismo programador si es que programara en asm) que se debe encargar en escribir las instrucciones necesarias para que la CPU pueda interpretar esos datos (mira este [hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10893392)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

¿Cómo sabes si la palabra *pie* es en Español o en Inglés?

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Tú lo sabes por contexto, si estás hablando en Español sabrás que te refieres a extremidades, si estás hablando en Inglés sabrás que te refieres a un delicioso postre.

De la misma manera que al examinar al RAM sabías que estabas trabajando con enteros de 4 bytes ¿cómo lo sabías? ¡No está anotado en la RAM! ¿Cómo sabías que era un entero de 4 bytes y no cuatro caracteres o la mitad de un entero de 8 bytes?: Por contexto.

C es un lenguaje compilado de tipado fuerte, cuando compilas un programa y dices explícitamente que un dato es un entero sin signo, queda compilado como tal y así lo interpretará el programa y el compilador porque así ha sido escrito.

Comment: +1 por la tarta

Answer (score 4):

Para hacer operaciones, C no necesita saber si el número es signed o unsigned porque las operaciones funcionan igual gracias al truco del complemento a 2.

Un ejemplo con 8 bits (para que quede manejable). En 8 bits caben 256 posibles combinaciones. Si se trata de `unsigned` esas combinaciones dan para representar números desde el cero (`00000000`) hasta el 255 (`11111111`).

Si en cambio se trata de `signed` las mismas combinaciones significan otra cosa. En ese caso si el primer bit es 0 los otros 7 se decodifican igual, con lo que tenemos para representar positivos desde cero (`00000000`) hasta 127 (`011111111`) pero si el primer bit es un 1 entonces es un negativo y para saber qué número es se hace su complemento a 2, de modo que el `10000000` representaría el -128 y el `11111111` sería el -1.

El complemento a 2 en realidad equivale a restarle 256 al número representado en binario considerado como `unsigned`. Así, el `10000000` que sería 128 como `unsigned`, al restarle 256 sale -128. Y el `11111111` que sería 255 como `unsigned`, da como resultado -1 al restarle 256.

Y gracias a ese truco la aritmética funciona automáticamente sin necesidad de saber lo que significan los bits. Mira, por ejemplo, sumemos los números `11111110` y `00001100`. La suma se hace "normal", bit a bit, siguiendo las reglas:

- 0+0 = 0
- 0+1 = 1+0 = 1
- 1+1 = 0 "y me llevo 1" (pues 1+1 es 2, que en binario es 10)
- 1+1+1 = 1 "y me llevo 1" (pues 1+1+1 es 3 que en binario es 11)

Así pues la suma saldría:

```
la que me llevo -->  1 1 1 1 1 1  
primer numero   -->    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
segundo numero  -->    0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
------------------------------------------------------
resultado       -->  1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

Ahora bien, **y esto es muy importante**, el resultado puede tener 9 bits como ha ocurrido en este caso, pero ya que estamos trabajando con enteros de 8 bits, el noveno bit "no cabe", por lo que se desprecia (sería un "bit de carry" que no forma parte del resultado). Por tanto ha salido `00001010`

Interpretemos el resultado. Si los números fueran `unsigned` el primero sería el 254 y el segundo sería el 12. Al sumarlos habría salido 266, que no cabe, por lo que el resultado obtenido en realidad ha sido 10 y estaría mal (eso se detectaría en la CPU porque el bit de carry quedó a 1).

Si los números fueran `signed` el primero sería el -2 y el segundo el 12, y al sumarlos debería salir 10 ¡que es lo que ha salido! En este caso el resultado estaría bien a pesar de que el bit de carry está a 1.

Por tanto la aritmética funciona correctamente y lo que cambia es la forma de detectar cuándo se ha producido desbordamiento. El compilador podría añadir instrucciones que comprueben el bit de carry cuando se trabaja con `unsigned`, o el bit de overflow (otro bit que genera la ALU cuando los bits de signo son inconsistentes entre los operandos y el resultado) si se trabajara con `signed`, para detectar cuándo se produce desbordamiento. En la práctica C no añade tales instrucciones, de modo que puedes tener desbordamientos sin que eso sea detectado. Es responsabilidad del programador operar con números cuyo resultado quepa en el formato utilizado. Así que en la práctica no hay diferencia a la hora de operar entre signed o unsigned (sí cambiarían las comparaciones entre enteros, ya que éstas se implementan mediante una resta seguida de una comprobación de desbordamiento, por tanto para hacer bien la comparación el compilador necesita conocer los tipos de las variables que está comparando).

A la hora de imprimirlos en cambio sí es necesario saber si el número es `signed` o no, ya que si mandamos imprimir un dato que en binario es `111111110`, debe mostrar 254 o -2 según sea `unsigned` o `signed`. Pero en el caso del C tampoco es relevante conocer el tipo del dato para imprimirlo, ya que `printf()` simplemente lo imprimirá como tú le pidas hacerlo, a través de una cadena de formato. Si pones `printf("%d", dato)` lo imprimirá como `signed`, mientras que si lo haces con `printf("%u", dato)` lo imprimirá como `unsigned`.

Comment: Si lo que dices es así, ¿de que sirve poner `unsigned` o no ponerlo en la declaración?

Comment: En algunos contextos sí afecta al código generado por el compilador, como al caso de la comparación. `a<b` necesita saber si los números son unsigned o no para compararlos, ya que `11111111` puede representar 255 o -1, y afectar a cómo se compara con 0 por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien la pregunta, al final, en C tiene la declaración de la variable indicas en el programa original en las definiciones el tipo... los bytes que son el int almacenado en memoria el programa se pueden interpretar y manipular de cualquiera de las dos formas, en C utiliza Complemento a 2: [Complemento a 1 y complemento a 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16827/complemento-a-1-y-complemento-a-2).

```
unsigned int a = 2147483648;
int b = (int)a;
// b == -1
```

En resumen... puedes tocar los valores en memoria pero no sus definiciones.
Suerte con Cheat Engine...

Answer (score 0):

El meollo del asunto es el tipo con el que declaras la variable donde vas a guardar un valor.

Cuando una vaeiable es `unsigned`, todos los bisg se utilizan para el valor numérico.... digamos que fueran 8 bits, en ese caso 0x00 es 0, 0x01 es 1, 0x10 es 16.... 0xff es 255. Si fuera `signed` se sacrifica el bit más significativo para el signo (0 es positivo, 1 es negativo) y se usa formato de complemento a 2. Usando los mismos 8 bits:

```
0x00 es 0
0x01 es 1
0x10 es 16
.
.
.
0x7e es 126
0x7f es 127
0x80 es -128
0x81 es -127
.
.
.
0xfe es -2
0xff es -1
```

Paro los números positivos hasta el 0x7f, se usan los mismos valores en ambos casos, pero subiendo en el dominio, hay un clash de valores. Esto es importante para c? En realidad no. A c no le puede importar menos. Al que le interesa es al que define los tipos de las variables. Si quieres meter un valor `signed` negativo en un `unsigned`, C te va a dejar. Desde el punto de vista binario, el valor es valido/correcto.... que no sea el valor esperado es algo a cargo del programador que está escribiendo las líneas de código respectivas.